# Extra zero in Android version code

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm building my release Android APK, I have the following attributes in my AndroidManifest.xml, inside my `<widget>` declaration:

```
version="1.0.0"
android-versionCode="11"
```

When I upload it to the Developer Console I'm seeing the following:

[image: screenshot of developer console]

Why am I getting a trailing zero at the end? Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version code and name are defined in your `build.gradle` file. Change them there (within `defaultConfig` part) and they should show properly.